# How does data standardization affect a classifier?

Tags: classification, standardization

How does standardization of data (subtracting the mean, dividing by standard deviation) affect classifiers? Namely, how (if at all) do different types of classifiers get affected by such an operation? I'm specifically looking at plug-in classifiers and nearest neighbor classifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to z-scores has an obvious effect on Euclidian distance and can alter relative distance between pairs of points. This has an immediate effect on methods that use distance directly, such as nearest neighbours.

For other methods the effect is often more subtle. Most methods have some form of regularization (SVM, neural networks, ...). Scaling data while keeping the regularization constant then changes the balance which in turn affects the resulting model.

Some approaches, like random forests, are completely unaffected by standardization because they essentially learn a suitable distance metric.